# Websphere 8.5.5.2 Liberty Profile – jdbc connection error

Tags: websphere, jdbctemplate, websphere-liberty

I am running WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.2/wlp-1.0.5.cl50220140403-1858 and trying to use InterSystems cacheDB jdbc driver: JDBC driver version  : 2014.1.1.702

This is producing this fatal error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Not supported at 
com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.getTypeMap(CacheConnection.java:1857) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

It appears that `getTypeMap` needs to be there and it is not. Is there a workaround for this?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that InterSystems JDBC Driver does not implement complete functionality, according to document found on http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/cache/20091/pdfs/BGJD.pdf, it seems that java.sql.Connection method getTypeMap is not supported. Try to contact InterSystems directly for help.

Comment: *It appears that getTypeMap needs to be there and it is not.* The method is there `com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.getTypeMap` and it's the one that's throwing the exception `java.sql.SQLException: Not supported at`. You probably should connect directly to database from your application instead of trying to going through Liberty Profile. Or, like Miljenko said contact the company directly.

Comment: What code is calling getTypeMap reflectively (i.e., what are the next few stack frames from the exception)? Even if the JDBC driver doesn't support the method, it's possible that some component in Liberty profile could handle this error better.